# Trello list guide gone

Tags: trello

I have been using Trello for a while and pretty much know how it works. Recently, I returned to the site and found out that the list guide on the left disappeared. I tried clicking on the left hand side bar, but it is not showing any more. Is there a setting I accidentally turned off?

Answer (score 1):

The 'list guide' on the left only appears (via the blue arrow) when the number of lists exceed what is viewable within the web page.  If you narrow the browser window, it should automatically appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

1. Update the Java plugin for the browser you are using to view the Trello board.
2. Use a different browser to view the Trello board.
3. There are little arrows on the left and right of the Trello board which hide the lists on right and left side. Click on them and the list should be back.

Hope this helps.